# Anyone know how to rectify a Windows 7 upgrade that killed Borland/Delphi licence?

Tags: windows, delphi

The same day that the monthly Windows 7 Professional upgrade was performed, Delphi 7 refused to run, giving only this message:

```
Register Delphi
---------------
Borland licence information was found, but it is not valid for Delphi.
You can not run Delphi without this information

Click the Exit button to exit Delphi
```

No further help was provided as to how to register Delphi, and it cannot be done through this App as it simply provides an exit option.

I am re-installing Delphi 7 as I wait (it is a school academic licence - i.e. free), but I suspect that the licence was somehow damaged by the Windows upgrade (and the site admin for my system has no clue).

Does anyone know how to correct this?

Comment: This isn't a suitable question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Please advise where I should ask - I thought I used S/O before?  Is it SuperUser maybe?   I'm a bit rusty here, sorry.

Comment: @Alexanderson contact Embarcadero support directly

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Answer (score 1):

There is a registration program called `D7reg.exe` in Delphi 7 installation directory (`C:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi7\Bin` if you used default installation location). You can use this program to change the registration information of your Delphi installation.

If you encounter a problem where registration screen has no text then download this patch from Embarcadero.

https://cc.embarcadero.com/item/28098